# Strange behavior with Svelte CSS

Tags: rollupjs, svelte

I just started a new Svelte app, and now when I make changes, rollup throws an error with whatever the first CSS rule I put in a module, like this:

```
[!] (svelte plugin) ParseError: Expected }
src\Register.svelte
1: form.svelte-1ietpyf{right:0}
```

If I kill the rollup process and restart, it works temporarily, but its kind of annoying.  Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Edit -- for clarity, i should add in some of the sample CSS:

```
<style>
    form {
        right:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal git repo reproducing the issue?

Comment: @RichHarris -- https://github.com/jaredwiener/sveltetest.  It only seems to happen when already running via `npm start dev` and then make a change.  For what its worth, I'm using VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue, and I've found a workaround. 
If you remove the css function in the rollup config's svelte options, it won't pass the css to the svelte compiler again (the issue is that the css is being processed as svelte code, but it's already compiled as css).

Maybe rollup is taking the outputted css file as an input file (unsure how exactly rollup works though).

So removing the css function will solve your issue :)